# Simple calculator ( ADD - Sub )

Tags: java, jgrasp

I am trying to develop a simple calculator software that looks like the picture below. It should ask the user to enter the first number, then the second number, and offer the user a choice to either (Add or Subtract), finally showing the result in the box below. 
So far I just did the GUI and I would like to know how can I add these codes to the code I've done.

[image]

Here is my code

```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
    class SimpleMath extends JFrame /*implements ActionListener*/
   { 

   private JLabel label ; //Firstnumber
   private JLabel labe2; // Second number 
   private JLabel labe3; // result 
   private JButton Add;// add 
   private JButton Sub; // subtrack
   private JTextField inputLine1;// enter the firstnumber 
    private JTextField inputLine2;//enter the second number
   private JTextArea  textArea;//the result

   public static void main (String [] args)
   {

   }

   public SimpleMath () {
    Container contentPane = getContentPane( );
         setSize      (300, 300);
         setResizable (false);
         setTitle     ("Simple Math");
         setLocation  (200, 300);
         contentPane.setLayout(null);

         //lebal 1 
         label = new JLabel("First number" ) ; 
         label. setBounds(15 , 30 , 150 , 50 ) ; 
         contentPane.add(label );

         //lebal2
          labe2 = new JLabel("Second number" ) ; 
         label. setBounds(15 , 30 ,1700 , 70 ) ; 
         contentPane.add(label );

         //lebal3
         labe3 = new JLabel("Result" ) ; 
         label. setBounds(15 , 30 ,200 , 100 ) ; 
         contentPane.add(label );


         //text input1 first number
         inputLine1 = new JTextField();
         inputLine1.setColumns(10);
         inputLine1.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 14));
         inputLine1. setBounds(15 , 70 , 150 , 25 ) ; 
         contentPane.add(inputLine1 );


         // text input2 second number 
         inputLine2 = new JTextField();
         inputLine2.setColumns(10);
         inputLine2.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 14));
         inputLine2. setBounds(15 , 70 , 150 , 25 ) ; 
         contentPane.add(inputLine2 );

         // add button 
         Add= new JButton("search ");
         Add. setBounds(200 , 70 , 220 , 60 ) ; 
         contentPane.add(Add) ;

         // sub button 
         Sub= new JButton("search ");
         Sub. setBounds(200 , 70 , 240 , 60 ) ; 
         contentPane.add(Sub) ;


         //text area that will show the result of the add and sub
         textArea = new JTextArea();
         textArea.setColumns(5);
         textArea.setRows(2);
         textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
         textArea.setEditable(false);
         textArea. setBounds(40 , 250 , 300 , 100 ) ; 
         contentPane.add(textArea); 

          return ; }}
```

Comment: Create a  instance of your JFrame, your main method is pretty empty

Comment: You just need to attach Event listeners to your buttons, do the operations in them and display the results

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: @JigarJoshi Thats correct, I don't where I can add the method? in a different class? than I add an object in the main? or how exactly? please advice.

Comment: As suggested in answers below, make an instance of `SimpleMath` in your main method, make that frame visible

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Netbeans to design your GUI then just double click "Add" button and add the following code to it

```
int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(inputline1.getText());
int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(inputline2.getText());
int sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;
textArea.setText(Integer.ToString(sum));
```

Comment: The question is tagged with jGrasp, I doubt they are using Netbeans.

Comment: then she has to add the above code to action listener of button

Comment: @ZohaibAslam Thanks, Can you advice please on how I can do the action listener please ?

Comment: in Netbeans it's possible by double clicking button in GUI builder, but in jgrasp i'm not sure :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read this topic to improve your layout.
[Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)
This is a very rich material about using layout managers in Swing.

You have to instantiate your JFrame in your main method. Here's a example:

```
SimpleMath sm = new SimpleMath();
sm.setVisible(true);
```

If you want the buttons to perform some action, you have to add action listeners to it. Here's a example of how I would do it:

```
Add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // Read the first number
        int first = Integer.parseInt(inputLine1.getText());
        // Read the second number
        int second = Integer.parseInt(inputLine2.getText());
        // Set the result
        int result = first + second;
        textArea.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Integer you can use double so that you can get values in decimal also.

```
double First = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());

// Read the Second number

double Second = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());

// Set the Result


double Result = First / Second;


    jLabel1.setText(String.valueOf(Result));
```